# How to display background image while no content?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with a `background-image` set. I will be dynamically adding content to this `div`, so I need it open with the `background-image`. For the background-image to show up, I did:

```
background-size:100% 100%;
```

Also,

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

But it does not show the image.  How do I get this working?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LGUFN/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LGUFN/4/ i have just updated fiddle check once

Comment: I want the height and width to be in percentage of original.

Comment: would you like to get the original size of the image?instead of getting image's in to background you can use <img src="" width="100%" height="100%"/> which will serve your purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;   
}

#container{
    background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d2/IPhone_4S_No_shadow.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    border: 1px solid #92b901;
    display: block;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do I set the image size to be 100% of the original size?

Comment: just remove     background-size:100% 100%;

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the height to its parents: `body` and `html`. Only then it will work.

Like so:

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Online example can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/LGUFN/1/

Answer (score 1):

Does your div have a size?
If it doesn't it will make the background the size of the div, which would then be 0 pixels in width and height.
Try adding:

```
#yourdiv
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Image is not displayed because `#container` does not have any `height`.

Add:

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
}
```

This will give `height` to `#container`.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LGUFN/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the parent of the div has no size too - so 100% won't work. Try something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;">
    <div class="bgimage" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    your content
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
body{
height:1000px;
}

div{
background:url('yourpic.jpg');      
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```